# MVC login action not redirecting after form authenticated

Tags: c#, forms-authentication

I have below controller login action.

[image]

Once everything done, `Redirect(returnUrl)` is not redirecting to "http://localhost:53821/Reviews/New" page. It is sitting in the same page.

```
[AllowAnonymous]
public ActionResult Login() {
  return this.View();
}

[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
public ActionResult Login(RH.ViewModel.LogOnVM logOn, string returnUrl) {
  if (ModelState.IsValid) {
    FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(logOn.Username, false);
    return this.Redirect(returnUrl);
  }

  return this.View(logOn);
}
```

Once it went through `[HttpPost]` Login, again it is hitting `[HttpGet]` login and same login view is getting displayed.

Answer (score 0):

Did you have `[Authorize]` in any controller?

```
[Authorize]
```

If the user is not authenticated, this `[Authorize]` will redirect you to the login page again, continuously.

Comment: User is getting authenticated properly.